# Issue with selenium IDE, "[error] testCase.debugContext.currentCommand() is undefined"

Tags: selenium, ide, selenium-ide, user-extensions.js

I am seeing the this error in a script that hasn't changed - but the Selenium version has. The error happens for me at an EndWhile loop that successfully executes 10+ times. I face this error.

```
[error] testCase.debugContext.currentCommand() is undefined
[error] Unexpected Exception: fileName -> chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-runner.js, lineNumber -> 157
```

After getting these errors, Selenium hangs and I have to close and reopen.

Is there any way to resolve this error ? Or any way so this error not face again. Kindly help.

Comment: Have your error anything to do with this bug?
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4335

Comment: Sounds like this is an issue with the plugin you use for this endwhile loop. I'd reconsider you need for this loop, and if you do in fact need it, should consider moving beyond selenium IDE.

Answer (score -1):

This keeps happening with Firefox 36.0.4, and vanilla Selenium IDE without any plugins.

You probably need to download a previous version of Firefox which is compatible with the current Selenium release.

Comment: U mean it is a compatibility issue? Any sources to prove your point?